# Change focus to dropdown element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/40ctx17s/). When I press the down/up key, i can successfully select the different value but the focus is still on the main input box. I want to move focus to the selected element. That is if i press down key and if selected element is John Doe, then the focus should also be on John doe element and not on the input box.

I set the following 2 things in the code but they are not working

```
$selected.focus();
```

and

```
$current.focus();
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: maybe becuase you didnt explicitly assign tabindex property for the list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just `focus()` a `<li>` element. From [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/focus/):

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`). In recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks on the element.

You can try setting the `tabindex` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly assign tabindex property for the list items if you want to focus on them. see http://jsfiddle.net/tkay/40ctx17s/1/ . But a downside to this is you will not be able to move further down in the list since input is not focused.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $listItems = $('li.autocomplete-list'),
        $div = $('div.autofill'),
        $input = $('#example');

    $div.hide();

    $('input#example').on('keydown', function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode,
            $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
            $current;

        $div.show();

        $listItems.removeClass('selected');

        if (key == 40) { // Down key
            $selected.focus();
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.eq(0);
            } else {
                $current = $selected.next();
            }
        } else if (key == 38) { // Up key
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.last();
            } else {
                $current = $selected.prev();
            }
        } else if (key == 13) {
            var value = $selected.text().split('(')[0].trim();
            $input.val(value) ;
            $div.hide();
        }

        if ($current) {
            $current.addClass('selected');
            $current.focus();
            console.log($current);
        }
    });


    $('li.autocomplete-list').on('click', function (e) {
        var value = $(this).text().split('(')[0].trim();
        $input.val(value);
        $div.hide();
    });

    $('li.autocomplete-list').hover(
        function(){ $(this).addClass('partial_selected') },
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('partial_selected') }
    );

});
```

```css
.selected {
    background: #a4a4a4;
}
.hover {
    background: #A9D0F5;
}
ul {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
li {
    padding: 6px 3px;
}
.autofill {
    width: 250px;
}
.input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 2.2em;
    padding: .3em .5em;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" name="example" id="example" placeholder="example..." autocomplete="off" list="examplelist" />

<div class="autofill">
    <ul class="autocomplete">
        <li class="autocomplete-list" tabindex="-1">John Doe (San Jose, CA)</li>
        <li class="autocomplete-list" tabindex="-1">Jane Doe (San Francisco, CA)</li>
        <li class="autocomplete-list" tabindex="-1">John Jane (San Carlos, CA)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Updated Answer after comments of OP**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $listItems = $('li.autocomplete-list'),
        $div = $('div.autofill'),
        $input = $('#example');

    $div.hide();

    $('input#example').on('keydown', function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode,
            $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
            $current;

        $div.show();

        $listItems.removeClass('selected');

        if (key == 40) { // Down key
            $selected.focus();
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.eq(0);
            } else {
                $current = $selected.next();
            }
        } else if (key == 38) { // Up key
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.last();
            } else {
                $current = $selected.prev();
            }
        } else if (key == 13) {
            if ($selected.length){
            e.preventDefault();
           }
            var value = $selected.text().split('(')[0].trim();
            $input.val(value) ;
            $div.hide();
        }

        if ($current) {
            $current.addClass('selected');
           
        }
    });


    $('li.autocomplete-list').on('click', function (e) {
        var value = $(this).text().split('(')[0].trim();
        $input.val(value);
        $div.hide();
    });

    $('li.autocomplete-list').hover(
        function(){ $(this).addClass('partial_selected') },
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('partial_selected') }
    );

    $("#frm").submit(function(){
        console.log('submitted');
    });
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background: #a4a4a4;
}
.hover {
    background: #A9D0F5;
}
ul {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
li {
    padding: 6px 3px;
}
.autofill {
    width: 250px;
}
.input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 2.2em;
    padding: .3em .5em;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm">
<input type="text" class="input" name="example" id="example" placeholder="example..." autocomplete="off" list="examplelist" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div class="autofill">
    <ul class="autocomplete">
        <li class="autocomplete-list">John Doe (San Jose, CA)</li>
        <li class="autocomplete-list">Jane Doe (San Francisco, CA)</li>
        <li class="autocomplete-list">John Jane (San Carlos, CA)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I cannot select the element with up and down key, then its completely breaking the whole thing. Is there any better approach I can use without breaking the existing functionality ?

Comment: Then you should not change focus to another element. autocomplete wont work if you'r input is not focused. Why do you want to focus on the current element?

Comment: Because when I press enter to select the dropdown value, it submits the form and event.preventDefault()  & event.stopPropogation() are not helping. So the only thing I can think of right now is to move away the focus.

Comment: @Raghuveer you can preventdefault the keydown event when enter key is clicked. check this http://jsfiddle.net/tkay/40ctx17s/10/

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/40ctx17s/6/)**

I have added a counter variable , and if `counter > 1` then only *key Up, Down, Enter method calls*, also on Enter Hit again i am setting `counter=0` so you get last selected Li. Instead of calling `removeClass('selected')` everytime, i am calling it only if my `counter >1`.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
    var $listItems = $('li.autocomplete-list'),
        $div = $('div.autofill'),
        $input = $('#example');

    $div.hide();
    var allLI = $(".autocomplete .autocomplete-list");
    var counter = 0;
    $('input#example').on('keydown', function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode,
            $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
            $current;
        //console.log("Show");
        $div.show();

        counter++;
        if (counter > 1) {
            if (key == 40) { // Down key
                $selected.focus();
                if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
                    $current = $listItems.eq(0);
                } else {
                    $current = $selected.next();
                }
            } else if (key == 38) { // Up key
                if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
                    $current = $listItems.last();
                } else {
                    $current = $selected.prev();
                }
            } else if (key == 13) {
                var value = $selected.text().split('(')[0].trim();
                $input.val(value);
                $div.hide();
                counter = 0;
            }

            if ($current) {
                allLI.removeClass('selected');
                $current.addClass('selected');
                $current.focus();
            }
        }
    });


    $('li.autocomplete-list').on('click', function (e) {
        var value = $(this).text().split('(')[0].trim();
        $input.val(value);
        $div.hide();
    });

    $('li.autocomplete-list').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).addClass('partial_selected')
    },

    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('partial_selected')
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the focus is still on the input box and not one the li element in your demo link

Comment: @Raghuveer: You want your cursor focus on Li tag. By this how you get your key up,Down method call as you have bind **keyevent** at `input#example`

Comment: @Raghuveer : Also want to know What you meant  by focus on dropdown **1)** You just want to highlight the matches LI tag (this is what i did in my answer) or  **2)** Set cursor position on Li.